# Invalid next.config.js options detected: The root value has an unexpected property, defaultConfig, which is not in the list of allowed properties

Tags: reactjs, next.js, config, bundle

### This is the issue I am getting.

```
- warn Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
- warn     The root value has an unexpected property, defaultConfig, which is not in the list of allowed properties (amp, analyticsId, assetPrefix, basePath, cleanDistDir, compiler, compress, configOrigin, crossOrigin, devIndicators, distDir, env, eslint, excludeDefaultMomentLocales, experimental, exportPathMap, generateBuildId, generateEtags, headers, httpAgentOptions, i18n, images, modularizeImports, onDemandEntries, optimizeFonts, output, outputFileTracing, pageExtensions, poweredByHeader, productionBrowserSourceMaps, publicRuntimeConfig, reactStrictMode, redirects, rewrites, sassOptions, serverRuntimeConfig, skipMiddlewareUrlNormalize, skipTrailingSlashRedirect, staticPageGenerationTimeout, swcMinify, target, trailingSlash, transpilePackages, typescript, useFileSystemPublicRoutes, webpack).
- warn See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
```

#### And here is my next.config.js file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    webpack(config) {
        const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.(".svg"));
        config.module.rules.push(
            {
                ...fileLoaderRule,
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                resourceQuery: /url/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
                resourceQuery: { not: /url/ },
                use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
            }
        );
        fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;
        return config;
    },
};

// module.exports = nextConfig;

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = (phase, defaultConfig) => {
    return withBundleAnalyzer(defaultConfig);
};
```

### I would be happy if you correct my mistake and explain it too:) Thanks

I expect both svgr and bundle-analyzer work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually write it like this without any issue

```js
// ... rest of the code..

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig)
```

Comment: what if I also have another plugin? 
lets say next-plugin-preval which also ask for the similar setup like this:

```
const createNextPluginPreval = require('next-plugin-preval/config');
const withNextPluginPreval = createNextPluginPreval();
module.exports = withNextPluginPreval(/* optionally add a next.js config */);
```

how will i combine 2 plugins in final module exports?

Comment: you can use function composition to combine multiple functions to apply in sequence. Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Could you show sample? I couldn't set it up correctly

Comment: something like this, module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(withNextPluginPreval(nextConfig));
But remember the order in which you apply the plugins can matter and lead to different outcomes. Also if my answer indeed solved your issue, please accept it as correct answer.